# React.JS: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been working on a front-end (following a tutorial) for React.js and have ran into an error:

> × Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I have looked into each one of these issues and cannot seem to find the problem.. If anyone has a pointer that would be very helpful..

**The 'App' Code:**

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, AppBar, Typography, Grow, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";

import memories from "./images/memories.png";
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Container maxwidth="lg">
      <AppBar position="static" color="inherit">
        <Typography variant="h2" align="center">
          Memories
        </Typography>
        <img src={memories} alt="memories" height="60" />
      </AppBar>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**The 'Package.json' Code:**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**The 'index.js' Code:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

EDIT: as requested, i've added a few more files which maybe causing the issue.

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted appears to be a hook call. Is there anywhere in your app that you call `useState`, `useRef`, or `useEffect`?

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`?

Comment: Here is the 'package.json' and the 'index.js', although, the only thing i've been editing between it working and not is the 'app.js' file.